# How can Random Forest variable importance be smaller for A compared to B when A has higher correlation with the response Y?

Tags: random-forest, importance

Suppose I am fitting a Random Forest model with A-F as my predictors and Y as my response variable.

I then calculate variable importance using the permutation method.

Why is it possible for variable importance be smaller for A compared to B when A has a much higher correlation with the response Y?

Comment: Plot your data - it might help

Comment: If correlation matters--as measured by the Pearson correlation coefficient--then you should be performing ordinary least squares regression rather than using a random forest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely.  Correlation gives the linear relationship between two variables.  It will (typically)  not be able to find  non-linear relationships.  Here's an (over?) simplified example. Suppose that x = 1:1000 and that y = +1 500 times and -1 the next 500 times. Then cor(x,y) < 1 (since y is non-linear). Then a simple tree with one split (x $\leq$ 500) will perfectly classify y.

Comment: Thank you! This makes perfect sense and makes things very clear

Comment: Thks, I don't like my example though.  I'm going to add a better one.

Comment: So here's another example I like better, although it's not perfect.  Predict x from abs(x) and sin(x).  If the interval of x is symmetric around 0, then cor(x,abs(x)) = 0.  Otoh, abs(x) will usually be a better predictor than sin(x).  I don't have time to run a tree though :).